# Whats wrong with my CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to get my name and trip input fields to line, but they're all over the place.
http://prime.programming-designs.com/test_forum/viewboard.php?board=0

```
#formdiv{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 30%;
}

.fielddiv1{

    background-color: #222222;
    border: 2px solid #333333;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}

.fielddiv2{

    background-color: #222222;
    border: 2px solid #333333;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.fieldtext{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `<br />` that's between those two `fielddiv1` div's

Answer (score 3):

You have a `<br>` between the divs that contain them.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap both of them (the two divs with fielddiv1 class) into a single div. And also delete the line break in between them.